# detached entity passed to persist on findAll call

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm getting

> detached entity passed to persist

when I call findAll Method of my repository.
I'm not even trying to persist anything , yet hibernate tells me that i passed a detached object to persist.

Here are my classes :

```
@Entity(name = "servicing_module")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Audited
@Getter
@Setter
public class ServicingModule extends AbstractAuditedEntity implements Serializable {

  

  @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="servicing_id")
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @JsonIgnore
  private Servicing servicing;


  @Basic
  private String name;

  @Column(unique = true)
  private String ins;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private ServicingModuleStateEnum state = ServicingModuleStateEnum.ACTIVE;

  @Basic
  private String description;

  @ElementCollection
  @Column(nullable = false)
  Set<String> contacts = new HashSet<>();

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
    ServicingModule that = (ServicingModule) o;
    return name.equals(that.name) && ins.equals(that.ins) && state == that.state && description.equals(that.description);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), name, ins, state, description);
  }

}
```

The parent class :

*/

```
@Entity(name = "servicing")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Audited
public class Servicing extends AbstractAuditedEntity {

@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "servicing", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<ServicingModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The repo

```
public interface ServicingModuleRepository extends AbstractEntityRepository<ServicingModule> {


  int countByInsStartingWithIgnoreCase(String partIns);
```

}

Thanks for your help

Comment: The stack trace might help you, but for something like this, it could be anywhere in the existing context - at some point within in it, something that is managed is made to reference something that isn't referenced. Anything read from the context is managed and discovered when a transaction commits, so check that you haven't called a set method on something while still in a transaction ie: ServicingModule.setServicing calls.